# std::bind with variadic template function

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, stdbind

I'm trying to write a generic obj factory using variadic template to call constructors of various classes. code as follow:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>
#include <unordered_map>

template<typename T>
class ObjFactory {
public:
    typedef std::shared_ptr<T>              ObjPtr;
    typedef std::function<ObjPtr(void)>     CreatorFunc;
public:
    void registerCreator(const std::string &name, const CreatorFunc &creator)
    { m_dictCreator[name] = creator; }

    ObjPtr getObj(const std::string &name) const
    {
        auto it = m_dictCreator.find(name);
        return (it == m_dictCreator.end() ? nullptr : (it->second)());
    }
private:
    std::unordered_map<std::string, CreatorFunc>   m_dictCreator;
};


using namespace std;

struct Base {
    virtual ~Base() {}
    virtual void greet() const
    { cout << "I am Base" << endl; }
};

struct Derived : Base {
    Derived() : x(0), y(0) {}
    Derived(int a, int b) : x(a), y(b) {}
    int x, y;

    virtual void greet() const
    { cout << "I am Derived x = " << x << " y = " << y << endl; }
};

template<typename T, typename... Args>
std::shared_ptr<T> create_obj(Args... args)  // This OK
// std::shared_ptr<T> create_obj(Args&&... args) // WRONG
{ return std::make_shared<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }

int main()
{
    ObjFactory<Base> factory;
    factory.registerCreator("default", create_obj<Derived>);
    factory.registerCreator("withArgs", std::bind(create_obj<Derived, int, int>, 1, 2));

    do {
        auto pObj = factory.getObj("default1");
        if (pObj) { pObj->greet(); }
    } while (0);

    do {
        auto pObj = factory.getObj("withArgs");
        if (pObj) { pObj->greet(); }
    } while (0);

    return 0;
}
```

In most examples, variadic arg always write like this "Args&&..." in function arg list. but this does not work with bind, compile error msg like this (clang-902.0.39.2)

> error: no viable conversion from '__bind
>   (&)(int &&, int
>         &&), int, int>' to 'const ObjFactory::CreatorFunc' (aka 'const function ()>')
>       factory.registerCreator("withArgs", std::bind(create_obj, 1, 2));

After removing the "&&", it works OK

But I don't know why?

Comment: This doesn't answer why, but replacing `std::bind` with a lambda (as is recommended in general) work as expected. `[](){ return create_obj<Derived>(1,2); }`

Comment: If interested, a considerably more minimal case of the OPs problem [can be found **here**](https://pastebin.com/Ud9KY8my).

Comment: `std::bind` make seance when you do not have C++11 otherwise you should use lambda.

Answer (score 1):

Universal references only work in a deduced context.  They do not function as you expect when the template parameters are explicitly specified.

Given the function template

```
template <typename... Args>
void foo(Args&&... args) {}
```

And the call

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
foo(a, b);
```

`Args` will be deduced to be `{int&, int&}`.  Reference collapsing is applied, and `int& &&` gets collapsed to just `int&`.  That means the types of the values in `args` are `{int&, int&}`.

If you call it with rvalues for arguments (i.e. `foo(1, 2)`) then `Args` will be deduced to be `{int, int}` and the types of the values in `args` become `{int&&, int&&}`.

---

That's the basics of universal references, so now let's look at what happens when you call

```
auto fn = std::bind(foo<int, int>, 1, 2);
fn();
```

Here, you've not allowed template argument deduction to take place so `Args` is `{int, int}` and `foo` is therefore expecting arguments of type `{int&&, int&&}`.  The values `1`, and `2` are copied into the bind object and passed to the callable as *lvalues* though.  Rvalue references can't bind to lvalues, and so the call fails to compile.

---

The way to make this work correctly is to use a lambda instead of `std::bind`:

```
auto fn = []() { foo(1, 2); };
fn();
```

With a lambda, template argument deduction works as normal, and `1`, and `2` remain rvalues.  Everything works as expected and the universal references do their job because they're being used in a deduced context.

Answer (score 0):

when using forwarding references you need to let argument being deduced otherwise you can't perfect forward them because you won't know the real type to use for them.

in your case you gave a type `create_obj<Derived, int, int>`
the function will be instantiated to `std::shared_ptr<Derived> create_obj(int&&, int&&)` and have no flexibility it will just be taking r-value int.

and you assigned the callable to a `const CreatorFunc&` and so the closure was `const` and your callable couldn't receive `const` arguments

replacing `create_obj<Derived, int, int>` by `create_obj<Derived, const int&, const int&>` which cause create_obj to be instantiated as `std::shared_ptr<Derived> create_obj(const int&, const int&)` will work in this case but would still not have the flexibility of forwarding references.

the real solution is to use lambda.

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much!